# Error in request approval action. Value cannot be null. Parameter Name: String nintex workflow error

Tags: workflow

I haven't given any parameter name like String in nintex workflow.

Doing same action through Nintex workflow OOB approve/Reject page it is working. doing with custom code only it is giving error.

Doing the same action in Development server it is not giving any error with custom code and it is working perfectly with custom code.

In development Server : Nintex workflow 2013(3.1.7.0)
In production Server: Nintex workflow 2013(3.1.2.0)

```
private string ApproveRejectNintexTask(SPWeb web, SPList taskList, int itemID, int decision, string comments)
    {
    SPListItem spTask = taskList.GetItemById(itemID);
    Guid commentsFieldId = Nintex.Workflow.Common.NWSharePointObjects.FieldComments;
    Guid decisionFieldId = Nintex.Workflow.Common.NWSharePointObjects.FieldDecision;
    Guid outcome = Nintex.Workflow.Common.NWSharePointObjects.FieldApprovalOutc‌​ome;
    spTask[decisionFieldId] = decision;
    spTask[commentsFieldId] = comments;
    spTask[outcome] = 2;
    spTask.Update();
    return comments;
 }
 Approval:0 Reject:1
```

Comment: For Approval/Rejecting i'm using a custom code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.